# Difference between last_name and user_lastname

Tags: author, user-meta

As per [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/), the method `get_the_author_meta()` has a `$field` argument with the following possible values:

- admin_color
- aim
- comment_shortcuts
- description
- display_name
- first_name
- ID
- jabber
- last_name
- nickname
- plugins_last_view
- plugins_per_page
- rich_editing
- syntax_highlighting
- user_activation_key
- user_description
- user_email
- user_firstname
- user_lastname
- user_level
- user_login
- user_nicename
- user_pass
- user_registered
- user_status
- user_url
- yim

I wonder, what is the difference between `last_name` and `user_lastname` (`first_name` and `user_firstname` respectively ).

**Which property am I supposed to use** and what are possible reasons that one might be filled, while at the same time the other is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer to "*Which property am I supposed to use*": **Use `first_name` and `last_name`**.

### Longer answer:

The properties `first_name`, `user_firstname`, `last_name` and `user_lastname` are defined in the [`WP_User` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/#source), and despite the different names (i.e. one with `user_` and the other without that prefix):

- Both `first_name` and `user_firstname` use the value of the `first_name` meta.
- Both `last_name` and `user_lastname` use the value of the `last_name` meta.

But `user_firstname` and `user_lastname` were the property names used in WordPress prior to version 2.0.0 (14 years ago..) — see `get_the_author_firstname()` and `get_the_author_lastname()` [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/2.0/wp-includes/template-functions-author.php#L31) and [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/1.5.2/wp-includes/template-functions-author.php#L38), and that properties are [still supported for backward compatibility](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L1093), but we should just use the ones *without* the `user_` prefix (e.g. `first_name` and not `user_firstname`).

```php
// Both of these return the same value - the value of the meta named first_name.
var_dump(
    get_the_author_meta( 'user_firstname' ), // works
    get_the_author_meta( 'first_name' )      // but better
);

// Both of these return the same value - the value of the meta named first_name.
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
var_dump(
    $current_user->user_firstname, // works
    $current_user->first_name      // but better/shorter...
);
```